# I cannot type space in interactive command mode

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, input

A very odd situation. If I enter into interactive commands - in this case `tasksh` and `nslookup` I cannot type whitespace. For example:

```
tasksh> add "my new task"
```

becomes

```
tasksh> add"mynewtask"
```

and does not work, naturally. I thought maybe this is something to do with `tasksh` but then I checked with `nslookup` in interactive mode - and it is the same thing. This happens on linux `4.6.7-1-MANJARO` but does not on OpenSUSE Leap 42.1.

How should I troubleshoot this very irksome thing?

I tried to run different terminals (gnome-terminal, xfce4-terminal, xterm) and it gives the same result.

Comment: I'd start by finding out about which version of libreadline you have and how that was built.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is Gnu Readline library, version 6.3. I might try to instll git version 7.2 from AUR, but I wonder if this is some configuration  problem.

Comment: Hmm, your pointer lead me to look into `~/.inputrc` and there was one line: `Space: magic-space` - I commented it out and it sorted the matter. I am unsure if I will have a problem with it elsewhere, but looks fine now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you've accidentally bound <kbd>Space</kbd> to a command that has no visible effect in one of your configuration files.

Check your shell initialization files for `stty` commands. That will directly affect at least programs that rely on the terminal's primitive line editor, and may indirectly affect programs that come with a decent line editor as they try to remain compatible with stty settings.

If the problem only occurs in certain programs, the problematic configuration may be that of the [readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readline) library. This library is used by bash and by a number of other programs. If the key works in bash but not in other programs that use readline, it may be because bash overrides it. The configuration file for readline is [`.inputrc`](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC9).

If you only have the problem in bash, check your `.bashrc` (which is where any terminal-related configuration should go) and other bash configuration files (in case the configuration is in the wrong place).

---

In a comment, you mention that `~/.inputrc` contains

> ```
> Space: magic-space
> ```

`magic-space` is a bash command. Other programs don't understand that. Either make this setting conditional to bash:

```
$if Bash
Space: magic-space
$endif
```

or remove this setting from `.inputrc` and define it in `.bashrc` instead:

```
bind 'Space: magic-space'
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the clear explanation. Now `.inputrc` works and I also know why.

Comment: Gilles, by "**terminal-related configuration should go**" - do you refer to other configuration besides `stty` commands?